# Persistent storage for WebDAV server on docker swarm?

Tags: docker, containers, swarm

How can I achieve a persistent storage for a WebDAV server running on several/any swarm nodes?
It's part of a docker-compose app running on my own vSphere infrastructure.

I was thinking about mounting an external NFS share from insde the containers (at the OS level, not docker volumes) but then how would that be better than having WebDAV outside the swarm cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options:

1. `Glusterfs`

This option is vSphere independent. You can create `replicated bricks` and store your volumes on them. Exposing same volume to multiple `docker hosts`. So in case of node failure the container will get restarted on another node and has it's persistent storage with it. You can also mount the persistent data on multiple containers.

There is one catch: Same diskspace will be consumed on multiple nodes.

2. [Docker-Volume-vSphere](https://github.com/vmware/docker-volume-vsphere)

This option requires `vsphere` hosts. You can create `docker` volumes on `vmfs` datastores. they will be shared between `docker` hosts (`virtual machines`). So in case of failure the container restarts on another node and has persistent data available. Multiple containers can share a single volume.